# 2D Game: bullet firing left and right

Tags: java, 2d-games

I have set up a bullet firing system in my 2D Game. where when the character is moving left the bullet is launched and moves left and well. this works for the right side aswell. but heres the problem... Say I shoot left  but before it exits the screen the character moves right, this change in direction also changes the direction of the already moving bullet and it moves to the right  like the character. I can make the bullet move back and forth with the left and right keys.

heres the bullet class. the move() method moves the bullet.

```
package gameLibrary;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Bullet {

int x,y, x2;
Image img;
boolean visible;

public Bullet(int startX, int startY) {
    x = startX;
    x2 = startX;
    y = startY;

ImageIcon newBullet = new             
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/bullet.png"));
img = newBullet.getImage();
    visible = true;

}
public void move(){

    if(Character.left){
        x -= 4;
        if(x < 0){
            visible = false;
            Character.left = false;
        }
    }
    if(Character.right) {
        x = x + 4;
        if(x > 854){
        visible = false; 
        Character.right = false;
    }
    }



}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public boolean getVisible(){
    return visible;
}
public Image getImage(){
    return img;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bullet needs to know its initial direction, so pass a boolean in the constructor and set a boolean member variable (maybe call it `moveLeft`). Then, in `move`, check the boolean member instead of checking `Character.left`. The `if (Character.right)` could just be an `else`.

Comment: ok thanks! that works. but now I have the problem when the character isnt moving the bullet fires but stays in the same location because the character was neither going left nor right.

Comment: is there something in java where we could check what the last key that was pressed was? either left or right? cause then I could just check that moveLeft && MoveRight == false and then use the last key pressed as the direction.

Comment: You need a [game loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure) to continuously update the state of objects in your game. That would where `Bullet.move()` should be called. Research Java [key events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) to find out more about input handling.